# Wifi connection keeps dropping on 16.04, sometimes would not connect to the network after more than 10 attempts

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, intel-wireless

Could this be a Wifi antenna issue? One of those wires connecting the antenna to the wireless card were damaged and I fixed it myself.

Here is the output of ifconfig and iwconfig:

ifconfig

```
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:2b:cb:ed:d5:8b  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:23505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1938591 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:1938591 (1.9 MB)

wlp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:77:37:81:48:a9  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff76:7b18:f50b:3817/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:209670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:246110201 (246.1 MB)  TX bytes:20791045 (20.7 MB)
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Ravit"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: B8:C1:A2:26:C9:7C   
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2671   Missed beacon:0
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Hey! Just added the output of the said command.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot.

If that does not fix the issue, do:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

But as you said, it may be a hardware problem with your antenna.